# How can I prevent the user from creating more than one record at a time in multirow block?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a form with a multi-row block based on a table.  The requirement is that the user can only enter 1 row into the block at a time and commit it.  They should not be allowed to create a second row before committing the first.

I tried using a WHEN-CREATE-RECORD trigger like this:

```
if :system.block_status = 'CHANGED' then
    alert('Can only create one record at a time');
end if;
```

However, this prevents me creating a new record even after committing changes.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to loop through all records and if the second record isn't null, alert the user.

```
DECLARE
    n_index NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    Go_block('block_name');

    first_record;

    WHILE :SYSTEM.last_record != 'TRUE' LOOP
        next_record;

        IF :block_name.item_name IS NOT NULL THEN --replace item_name with one which the user will enter all the time
          n_index := n_index + 1;
        END IF;

        IF n_index > 0 THEN
          Alert('Only one record can be created at a time!');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Where would I do this?  e.g. the user might create a new row just by clicking the mouse below the last record (or can I prevent that?)

Comment: you can do it on `when-create-record` or `when-validate-record` - see which works fine for you @Shaz

Comment: @SathyajithBhat @Shaz I believe `when-create-record` or `when-validate-record` triggers couldn't support `go_block` or `next_record` lines (because they are restricted procedures) so this looping solution wouldn't exactly work on creating new record.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
  -- WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE
  IF :SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD > 1 THEN
    DELETE_RECORD;
  END IF;
END;
```